# Implementing versioning system with MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design

I know this has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536819/how-to-keep-history-of-record-updates-in-mysql) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15416332/how-to-create-a-versioning-history-revision-system-for-contents-published-by-use), but I have the same idea with a different possible implementation and I need some help.

Initially I had my `blogstories` table with this structure:

```
| Column    | Type        | Description                                    |
|-----------|-------------|------------------------------------------------|
| uid       | varchar(15) | 15 characters unique generated id              |
| title     | varchar(60) | story title                                    |
| content   | longtext    | story content                                  |
| author    | varchar(10) | id of the user that originally wrote the story |
| timestamp | int         | integer generated with microtime()             |
```

After I decided I wanted to implement some versioning system for every story on the blog, the first thing that came to my mind was creating a different table to hold **edits**; after that, I thought I could modify the existing table to hold **versions** instead of **edits**. This is the structure that came to my mind:

```
| Column        | Type          | Description                                       |
|------------   |-------------  |------------------------------------------------   |
| story_id      | varchar(15)   | 15 characters unique generated id                 |
| version_id    | varchar(5)    | 5 characters unique generated id                  |
| editor_id     | varchar(10)   | id of the user that commited                      |
| author_id     | varchar(10)   | id of the user that originally wrote the story    |
| timestamp     | int           | integer generated with microtime()                |
| title         | varchar(60)   | current story title                               |
| content       | longtext      | current story text                                |
| coverimg      | varchar(20)   | cover image name                                  |
```

The reasons why I came here:

- The `uid` field of the initial table was UNIQUE in the table. Now, the `story_id` is not unique anymore. How should I deal with that? (I thought I could address `story_id = x` and then find the latest version, but that seems very resource consuming, so please give your advice)
- `author_id` field value is repeating in each every row of the table. Where and how should I keep it?

---

**Edit**

The unique codes generation process is in the `CreateUniqueCode` function:

```php
trait UIDFactory {
  public function CryptoRand(int $min, int $max): int {
    $range = $max - $min;
    if ($range < 1) return $min;
    $log = ceil(log($range, 2));
    $bytes = (int) ($log / 8) + 1;
    $bits = (int) $log + 1;
    $filter = (int) (1 << $bits) - 1;
    do {
        $rnd = hexdec(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($bytes)));
        $rnd = $rnd & $filter;
    } while ($rnd >= $range);
    return $min + $rnd;
  }
  public function CreateUID(int $length): string {
    $token = "";
    $codeAlphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $codeAlphabet.= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    $codeAlphabet.= "0123456789";
    $max = strlen($codeAlphabet) - 1;
    for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $token .= $codeAlphabet[$this->CryptoRand(0, $max)];
    }
    return $token;
  }
}
```

The code is written in [Hack](http://hacklang.org), and was originally written in PHP by [@Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1698153/scott) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846202/php-how-to-generate-a-random-unique-alphanumeric-string/13733588#13733588).

The fields `author_id` and `editor_id` **can be** different, because there are users with enough permissions to edit anyone's stories.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Analyzing the scenario —which presents characteristics associated with the subject known as *temporal databases*— from a conceptual perspective, one can determine that: (a) a “present” *Blog Story Version* and (b) a “past” *Blog Story Version*, although very resembling, are entities of different types.

In addition to that, when working at the logical level of abstraction, facts (represented by rows) of distinct kinds must be retained in distinct tables. In the case under consideration, even when quite similar, (i) facts about “present” *Versions* are different from (ii) facts about “past” *Versions*.

Therefore I recommend managing the situation by means of two tables:

- one dedicated exclusively for the “current” or “present” *Versions* of the *Blog Stories*, and
- one that is separate, but also linked with the other, for all the “previous” or “past” *Versions*;

each with (1) a slightly distinct number of columns and (2) a different group of constraints.

Back to the conceptual layer, I consider that —in your business environment— *Author* and *Editor* are notions that can be delineated as *Roles* that can be played by a *User*, and these important aspects depend on data *derivation* (via logical-level manipulation operations) and *interpretation* (carried out by the *Blog Stories* readers and writers, at the external level of the computerized information system, with the assistance of one or more application programs).

I will detail all these factors and other relevant points as follows.

## Business rules

According to my understanding of your requirements, the following business rules formulations (put together in terms of the relevant entity types and their kinds of interrelationships) are specially helpful in establishing the corresponding *conceptual* schema:

- A *User* writes zero-one-or-many *BlogStories*
- A *BlogStory* holds zero-one-or-many *BlogStoryVersions*
- A *User* wrote zero-one-or-many *BlogStoryVersions*

**Expository IDEF1X diagram**

Consequently, in order to expound my suggestion by virtue of a graphical device, I have created a sample IDEF1X<sup>**a**</sup> diagram that is derived from the business rules formulated above and other features that seem pertinent. It is shown in [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atqvq.jpg):

[image: Figure 1 - Blog Story Versions IDEF1X Diagram]

**Why are *BlogStory* and *BlogStoryVersion* conceptualized as two different entity types?**

Because:

- A *BlogStoryVersion* instance (i.e., a “past” one) always holds a value for an *UpdatedDateTime* property, while a *BlogStory* occurrence (i.e., a “present” one) never holds it.
- Besides, the entities of those types are uniquely identified by the values of two distinct sets of properties: *BlogStoryNumber* (in the case of the *BlogStory* occurrences), and *BlogStoryNumber* plus *CreatedDateTime* (in the case of the *BlogStoryVersion* instances).

---

<sub><sup>**a**</sup> *Integration Definition for Information Modeling* ([IDEF1X](http://www.idef.com/idef1x-data-modeling-method/)) is a highly recommendable data modeling technique that was established as a *standard* in December 1993 by the United States *National Institute of Standards and Technology* (NIST). It is based on the early theoretical material authored by the *sole originator* of the [relational model](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=362685), i.e., [Dr. E. F. Codd](http://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/codd_1000892.cfm); on the [Entity-Relationship](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=320440) view of data, developed by [Dr. P. P. Chen](http://awards.acm.org/award_winners/chen_6196475.cfm); and also on the Logical Database Design Technique, created by Robert G. Brown.</sub>

---

## Illustrative logical SQL-DDL layout

Then, based on the conceptual analysis previously presented, I declared the logical-level design below:

```
-- You should determine which are the most fitting 
-- data types and sizes for all your table columns 
-- depending on your business context characteristics.

-- Also you should make accurate tests to define the most
-- convenient index strategies at the physical level.

-- As one would expect, you are free to make use of 
-- your preferred (or required) naming conventions.    

CREATE TABLE UserProfile (
    UserId          INT      NOT NULL,
    FirstName       CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    LastName        CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    BirthDate       DATETIME NOT NULL,
    GenderCode      CHAR(3)  NOT NULL,
    UserName        CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CreatedDateTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
    --
    CONSTRAINT UserProfile_PK  PRIMARY KEY (UserId),
    CONSTRAINT UserProfile_AK1 UNIQUE ( -- Composite ALTERNATE KEY.
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        BirthDate,
        GenderCode
    ), 
    CONSTRAINT UserProfile_AK2 UNIQUE (UserName) -- ALTERNATE KEY.
);

CREATE TABLE BlogStory (
    BlogStoryNumber INT      NOT NULL,
    Title           CHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    Content         TEXT     NOT NULL,
    CoverImageName  CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    IsActive        BIT(1)   NOT NULL,
    AuthorId        INT      NOT NULL,
    CreatedDateTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
    --
    CONSTRAINT BlogStory_PK              PRIMARY KEY (BlogStoryNumber),
    CONSTRAINT BlogStory_AK              UNIQUE      (Title), -- ALTERNATE KEY.
    CONSTRAINT BlogStoryToUserProfile_FK FOREIGN KEY (AuthorId)
        REFERENCES UserProfile (UserId)
);

CREATE TABLE BlogStoryVersion  (
    BlogStoryNumber INT      NOT NULL,
    CreatedDateTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
    Title           CHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    Content         TEXT     NOT NULL,
    CoverImageName  CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    IsActive        BIT(1)   NOT NULL,
    AuthorId        INT      NOT NULL,
    UpdatedDateTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
    --
    CONSTRAINT BlogStoryVersion_PK              PRIMARY KEY (BlogStoryNumber, CreatedDateTime), -- Composite PK.
    CONSTRAINT BlogStoryVersionToBlogStory_FK   FOREIGN KEY (BlogStoryNumber)
        REFERENCES BlogStory (BlogStoryNumber),
    CONSTRAINT BlogStoryVersionToUserProfile_FK FOREIGN KEY (AuthorId)
        REFERENCES UserProfile (UserId),
    CONSTRAINT DatesSuccession_CK               CHECK       (UpdatedDateTime > CreatedDateTime) --Let us hope that MySQL will finally enforce CHECK constraints in a near future version.
);
```

Tested [in this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0ccf6) that runs on MySQL 5.6.

**The `BlogStory` table**

As you can see in the demo design, I have defined the `BlogStory` PRIMARY KEY (PK for brevity) column with the INT datatype. In this regard, you may like to fix a built-in automatic process that generates and assigns a numeric value for such a column in every row insertion. If you do not mind leaving gaps occasionally in this set of values, then you can employ the [AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) attribute, commonly used in MySQL environments.

When entering all your individual `BlogStory.CreatedDateTime` data points, you can utilize the [NOW() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now), which returns the *Date and Time* values that are current in the database server at the exact INSERT operation instant. To me, this practice is decidedly more suitable and less prone to errors than the use of external routines.

Provided that, as discussed in (now-removed) comments, you want to avoid the possibility of maintaining `BlogStory.Title` duplicate values, you have to set up a [UNIQUE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) constraint for this column. Due to the fact that a given *Title* may be shared by several (or even all of the) “past” *BlogStoryVersions*, then a UNIQUE constraint should *not* be established for the `BlogStoryVersion.Title` column.

I included the `BlogStory.IsActive` column of type [BIT(1)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-type.html) (though a [TINYINT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) may as well be used) in case you need to provide “soft” or “logical” DELETE functionality.

**Details about the `BlogStoryVersion` table**

On the other hand, the PK of the `BlogStoryVersion` table is composed of (a) `BlogStoryNumber` and (b) a column named `CreatedDateTime` that, of course, marks the precise instant in which a `BlogStory` row underwent an INSERT.

`BlogStoryVersion.BlogStoryNumber`, besides being part of the PK, is also constrained as a FOREIGN KEY (FK) that references `BlogStory.BlogStoryNumber`, a configuration that enforces *referential integrity* between the rows of these two tables. In this respect, implementing an automatic generation of a `BlogStoryVersion.BlogStoryNumber` is not necessary because, being set as a FK, the values INSERTed into this column must be “drawn from” the ones already enclosed in the related `BlogStory.BlogStoryNumber` counterpart.

The `BlogStoryVersion.UpdatedDateTime` column should retain, as expected, the point in time when a `BlogStory` row was modified and, as a consequence, added to the `BlogStoryVersion` table. Hence, you can use the NOW() function in this situation too.

The *Interval* comprehended between `BlogStoryVersion.CreatedDateTime` and `BlogStoryVersion.UpdatedDateTime` expresses the entire *Period* during which a `BlogStory` row was “present” or “current”.

**Considerations for a `Version` column**

It can be useful to think of `BlogStoryVersion.CreatedDateTime` as the column that holds the value that represents a particular “past” *Version* of a *BlogStory*. I deem this much more beneficial than a `VersionId` or `VersionCode`, since it is user-friendlier in the sense that people tend to be more familiar with *time* concepts. For instance, the blog authors or readers could refer to a *BlogStoryVersion* in a fashion similar to the following:

- “I want to see the specific *Version* of the *BlogStory* identified by *Number* `1750` that was *Created* on `26 August 2015` at `9:30`”.

**The *Author* and *Editor* Roles: Data derivation and interpretation**

With this approach, you can easily distinguish who holds the “original” `AuthorId` of a concrete *BlogStory* SELECTing the “earliest” *Version* of a certain `BlogStoryId` FROM the `BlogStoryVersion` table by virtue of applying the [MIN() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) to `BlogStoryVersion.CreatedDateTime`.

In this way, each `BlogStoryVersion.AuthorId` value contained in *all* the “later” or “succeeding” *Versions* rows indicate, naturally, the *Author* identifier of the respective *Version* at hand, but one can also say that such a value is, at the same time, denoting the *Role* played by the involved *User* as *Editor* of the “original” *Version* of  a *BlogStory*.

Yes, a given `AuthorId` value may be shared by multiple `BlogStoryVersion` rows, but this is actually a piece of information that tells something very significant about each *Version*, so the repetition of said datum is *not* a problem.

**The format of DATETIME columns**

As for the DATETIME data type, yes, you are right, “[MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in '`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`' format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)”, but you can confidently enter the pertinent data in this manner, and when you have to perform a query you just have to make use of the built-in [DATE and TIME functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) in order to, among other things, show the concerning values in the appropriate format for your users. Or you could certainly carry out this kind of data formatting via your application programms(s) code.

**Implications of `BlogStory` UPDATE operations**

Every time that a `BlogStory` row suffers an UPDATE, you *must ensure* that the corresponding values that were “present” until the modification took place are then INSERTed into the `BlogStoryVersion` table. Thus, I highly suggest fulfilling these operations within a single [ACID TRANSACTION](http://amturing.acm.org/info/gray_3649936.cfm#add_1) to guarantee that they are treated as an indivisible Unit of Work. You may as well employ TRIGGERS, but they tend to make things untidy, so to speak.

## Introducing a `VersionId` or `VersionCode` column

If you opt (because of business circumstances or personal preference) to incorporate a `BlogStory.VersionId` or `BlogStory.VersionCode` column to distinguish the *BlogStoryVersions*, you should ponder the following possibilities:

1. A `VersionCode` could be required to be UNIQUE in (i) the whole `BlogStory` table and also in (ii) `BlogStoryVersion`.

   Therefore, you have to implement a *carefully tested and totally reliable* method in order to generate and assign each `Code` value.
2. Maybe, the `VersionCode` values could be repeated in different `BlogStory` rows, but *never* duplicated along with the same `BlogStoryNumber`. E.g., you could have:

   - a *BlogStoryNumber `3` - Version `83o7c5c`* and, simultaneously,
   - a *BlogStoryNumber `86` - Version `83o7c5c`* and
   - a *BlogStoryNumber `958` - Version `83o7c5c`*.

The later possibility opens another alternative:

3. Keeping a `VersionNumber` for the `BlogStories`, so there could be:

   - *BlogStoryNumber `23` - Versions `1, 2, 3…`*;
   - *BlogStoryNumber `650` - Versions `1, 2, 3…`*;
   - *BlogStoryNumber `2254` - Versions `1, 2, 3…`*;
   - etc.

## Holding “original” and “subsequent” versions in a single table

Although maintaining all the *BlogStoryVersions* in the *same* individual *base* table is possible, I suggest not to do it because you would be mixing two distinct (conceptual) types of facts, which thus has undesirable side-effects on

- data constraints and manipulation (at the logical level), along with
- the related processing and storage (at the physical tier).

But, on condition that you choose to follow that course of action, you can still take advantage of many of the ideas detailed above, e.g.:

- a *composite* PK consisting of an INT column (`BlogStoryNumber`) and a DATETIME column (`CreatedDateTime`);
- the usage of *server functions* in order to optimize the pertinent processes, and
- the *Author* and *Editor* derivable *Roles*.

Seeing that, by proceeding with such an approach, a `BlogStoryNumber` value will be *duplicated* as soon as “newer” *Versions* are added, an option that and that you could evaluate (which is very alike to those mentioned in the previous section) is establishing a `BlogStory` PK composed of the columns `BlogStoryNumber` and `VersionCode`, in this manner you would be able to uniquely identify each *Version* of a *BlogStory*. And you can try with a combination of `BlogStoryNumber` and `VersionNumber` too.

## Similar scenario

You may find my answer to [this question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107354/storing-created-retired-dates-for-a-large-amount-of-different-entities/107575#107575) of help, since I as well propose enabling *temporal* capabilities in the concerning database to deal with a comparable scenario.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to use Version Normal Form (vnf). The advantages include:

- The current data and all past data reside in the same table.
- The same query is used to retrieve current data or data that was current as of any particular date.
- Foreign key references to versioned data work the same as for unversioned data.

An additional benefit in your case, as versioned data is uniquely identified by making the effective date (the date the change was made) part of the key, a separate version_id field is not required.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32060076/which-option-would-be-better-for-historical-information-of-a-table/32104764#32104764) is an explanation for a very similar type of entity.

More details can be found in a slide presentation [here](http://www.slideshare.net/TommCarr/bitemporal-rdbms-2014) and a not-quite-completed document [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8hnkzet6fueblz7/TemporalDBDesign.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: Underrated answer

Answer (score 1):

Your relation

```
(story_id, version_id, editor_id, author_id, timestamp, title, content , coverimg)
```

is not in 3rd normal form. For every version of your story the author_id is the same. So you need two relations to overcome this

```
(story_id, author_id)
(story_id, version_id, editor_id, timestamp, title, content , coverimg)
```

The key of the first relation is `story_id`, the key of the second relation is the combined key `(story_id, version_id)`. If you don't like combined key then you can use only `version_id` as key

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve my problem, it just emphasizes them

Comment: So it doesn't even answer the query '`author_id` *field value is repeating in each every row of the table. Where and how should I keep it*'?

Comment: I do not really understand what your answer states. It might be because I am not a native English speaker, so could you try to explain it in more and simple words, please?

Comment: It means that you should avoid the repetition of the author_id number (if the story_id is equal for two rows, their  author_id is equal, too) and split your table in the two tables as described in my post. So you can avoid the repetition of author_id.