# Database layout to keep track of the "freshness" of a column value in a specific row

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema, data-versioning

I have a `Person` with columns like `name`, `address` and `bio`.
How do I store data in order to know the "freshness" of these columns?

For instance, *"for the Person Y, the name has changed 2 days ago, and the location 2 weeks ago"*.

Is this simply a versioning problem?

```
Person v1 - name: A1, address: B1, bio: C1, updated_at: 4.days.ago
Person v2 - name: A2, address: B1, bio: C1, updated_at: 3.days.ago
Person v3 - name: A2, address: B1, bio: C2, updated_at: 1.days.ago
```

And after I look trough different versions to find the last one with a different column?

Or is there better ways to handle that? Put freshness data in another table? Or even DB?

I will normally use MySQL, unless this can be solved by means of another database management system.

Regards.

#### Additional details

Thank you for you comments and answers, but I was forgetting something: Actually, I need to know when the column value was updated, but by who as well.
Something like *"updated at XX by User Y"*.

Comment: You may find of help [this Q & A](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/112314/63644) about a scenario involving history tables and/or versioning (i.e., *temporal* requirements).

Answer (score 0):

With MariaDB 10.3 you can use [system-versioned tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/temporal-data-tables/).

You can then see all the versions of a particular row with a query like:

```
SELECT *, ROW_START, ROW_END FROM Person WHERE id = 4 FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL;
```

Also, with the `AS OF` syntax you can get the version of the row that existed at a particular time:

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE id = 4 FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP '2019-08-08 15:10:00';
```

See also this post in the MariaDB blog: [Automatic Data Versioning in MariaDB Server 10.3](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/automatic-data-versioning-in-mariadb-server-10-3/).

**EDIT**

If you need to know who made a change, this will probably have to be controlled through your software. You can add a special `last_change_by` column in the table e.g. something like:

```
ALTER TABLE Person ADD last_change_by varchar(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you are looking at you need to create an audit system that will record several points of data about every insert/update/delete for the information you want to know. You can set it up so it monitors every column or just the ones that a user can change or you care about knowing when they changed. This will provide an added benefit of using less storage space when only one or a few columns change or if there are not many columns that the user can change to begin with.

Audit Information

- Table where data is changed
- Column that was changed
- Date/Time of change
- User who made the change
- Old value
- New value